# sass error when running LMS in edx-plateform

Tags: css, openedx

I'm trying to run the lms of edx-plateform but i keep getting this error

> CompileError: Error: Undefined variable: "$verdana".
>           on line 314 of lms/static/sass/partials/base/_variables.scss
>     $sans-serif: $verdana !default;
>       -----------------^

that's what is written inside the _variablesscss file

```
$sans-serif: 'Open Sans', $verdana, sans-serif !default;
$monospace: Monaco, 'Bitstream Vera Sans Mono', 'Lucida Console', 
monospace !default;
$body-font-family: $sans-serif !default;
$serif: $georgia !default;
```

I'm not sure what to do to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to **add** a definition for the `$verdana` variable in your _variablesscss file:

```
$verdana: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif !default;
```

Or simply remove the `$verdana` variable from your `$sans-serif` variable.

```
$sans-serif: 'Open Sans', Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif !default;
```

Comment: that's what i'm getting now CompileError: Error: Undefined variable: "$georgia".
        on line 319 of lms/static/sass/partials/base/_variables.scss
>> $serif: $georgia !default;

Comment: i replaced the $georgia with these Georgia, Cambria, serif and now i'm getting this error       `CompileError: Error: no mixin named clearfix

       Backtrace:
        lms/static/sass/shared-v2/_header.scss:13
        on line 13 of lms/static/sass/shared-v2/_header.scss
>>         @include clearfix();`

Comment: If you don't need the `clearfix()` mixin, you might as well remove the `@include clearfix();`

Comment: removing the clearfix mixin will result into other errors, I can't just keep deleting stuff